# creation of sql database impossible

Tags: azure, sql

When trying to create a SQL database in the Azure Cloud I always get a validation error. Neither the database nor the database server are created as result.
I have no clue about the reason for this. Thanks for any help. According to the system administrator, I should have the permission to create an SQL database.

The error message is given below:

````
    "authorization": {
        "action": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action",
        "scope": "/subscriptions/f0beb7c8-f815-46ea-a8f8-9787820cf3f4/resourceGroups/rg-bkw-augias-test-we/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Microsoft.SQLDatabase.newDatabaseNewServer_fc9cf351b54145b09f323"
    },
    "caller": "tim.vorderbrueck@hslu.ch",
    "channels": "Operation",
    "claims": {
        "aud": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
        "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/376e33ca-d656-4e46-8bcb-7d5ba898ae66/",
        "iat": "1614947673",
        "nbf": "1614947673",
        "exp": "1614951573",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference": "1",
        "aio": "AWQAm/8TAAAAJ4qo51VmekVyCL69cIY9fbgFMpkRUoSVnJhxuyFMAr3py/+9Q0sXs2wm/cWL/snDWpdG+/uR/p8lVeDhEUuZHeVqy3Gpi6jcc1QcUhCH2L9+6UEluTCjIx6jiXw6YeTQ",
        "altsecid": "5::10037FFEA84DABF2",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences": "pwd",
        "appid": "c44b4083-3bb0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c",
        "appidacr": "2",
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress": "tim.vorderbrueck@hslu.ch",
        "groups": "df261278-ed9f-4dd8-85f7-eee24ad82b3e",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider": "https://sts.windows.net/75a34008-d7d1-4924-8e78-31fea86f6e68/",
        "ipaddr": "147.88.56.32",
        "name": "vor der Brück Tim HSLU I",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier": "df846aac-6729-4c7b-a58e-fdcc1491fe13",
        "puid": "100320008DB29C91",
        "rh": "0.AQkAyjNuN1bWRk6Ly31bqJiuZoNAS8SwO8FJtH2XTlPL3zwJALg.",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope": "user_impersonation",
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "mG17QuV3wZF3j5YDMttkBLJKJ4rGfO0SZcDCb1FofBw",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid": "376e33ca-d656-4e46-8bcb-7d5ba898ae66",
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "tim.vorderbrueck@hslu.ch",
        "uti": "wOvpZBKoUE6vS0QnHIEUAA",
        "ver": "1.0",
        "xms_tcdt": "1365059082"
    },
    "correlationId": "b93a2cbd-ac46-467b-a930-cb43c1c7ba56",
    "description": "",
    "eventDataId": "1dbbe425-68f2-4063-8fc4-8fdf93d3e4c7",
    "eventName": {
        "value": "EndRequest",
        "localizedValue": "End request"
    },
    "category": {
        "value": "Policy",
        "localizedValue": "Policy"
    },
    "eventTimestamp": "2021-03-05T12:54:54.2637467Z",
    "id": "/subscriptions/f0beb7c8-f815-46ea-a8f8-9787820cf3f4/resourceGroups/rg-bkw-augias-test-we/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/dbservernonprod/databases/testdb/events/1dbbe425-68f2-4063-8fc4-8fdf93d3e4c7/ticks/637505456942637467",
    "level": "Error",
    "operationId": "b93a2cbd-ac46-467b-a930-cb43c1c7ba56",
    "operationName": {
        "value": "Microsoft.Authorization/policies/deny/action",
        "localizedValue": "'deny' Policy action."
    },
    "resourceGroupName": "rg-bkw-augias-test-we",
    "resourceProviderName": {
        "value": "Microsoft.Sql",
        "localizedValue": "Microsoft SQL"
    },
    "resourceType": {
        "value": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments"
    },
    "resourceId": "/subscriptions/f0beb7c8-f815-46ea-a8f8-9787820cf3f4/resourceGroups/rg-bkw-augias-test-we/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/dbservernonprod/databases/testdb",
    "status": {
        "value": "Failed",
        "localizedValue": "Failed"
    },
    "subStatus": {
        "value": "",
        "localizedValue": ""
    },
    "submissionTimestamp": "2021-03-05T12:56:10.1971835Z",
    "subscriptionId": "f0beb7c8-f815-46ea-a8f8-9787820cf3f4",
    "tenantId": "376e33ca-d656-4e46-8bcb-7d5ba898ae66",
    "properties": {
        "isComplianceCheck": "False",
        "resourceLocation": "switzerlandnorth",
        "ancestors": "mg-bkw-nonprod-we,mg-bkw-we,mg-bkwgroup,376e33ca-d656-4e46-8bcb-7d5ba898ae66",
        "policies": "[{\"policyDefinitionId\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/mg-bkw-we/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/denyLocationsWE/\",\"policyDefinitionName\":\"denyLocationsWE\",\"policyDefinitionEffect\":\"Deny\",\"policyAssignmentId\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/mg-bkw-we/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/denyLocationsWE/\",\"policyAssignmentName\":\"denyLocationsWE\",\"policyAssignmentScope\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/mg-bkw-we\",\"policyAssignmentParameters\":{\"allowedLocations\":{\"value\":[\"westeurope\",\"northeurope\"]}},\"policyExemptionIds\":[]}]",
        "eventCategory": "Policy",
        "entity": "/subscriptions/f0beb7c8-f815-46ea-a8f8-9787820cf3f4/resourceGroups/rg-bkw-augias-test-we/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/dbservernonprod/databases/testdb",
        "message": "Microsoft.Authorization/policies/deny/action",
        "hierarchy": ""
    },```
````

Answer (score 1):

You have an Azure policy in place in your subscription which denies the creation of Azure SQL Databases. You will need to talk to whoever manages your subscriptions and get them to remove or exempt you from this policy.

```
    "operationName": {
        "value": "Microsoft.Authorization/policies/deny/action",
        "localizedValue": "'deny' Policy action."
    },
```